# OpenStreetMap overrides map div position

Tags: css, openlayers, openstreetmap

I'm starting to learn the OpenStreetMap / OpenLayers API to put maps in my web app. While I've got to grips with the mapping itself, I've found that the div which contains the map won't stay where I put it. Here's my code so far:

#### maptest.htm

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>OpenStreetMap Test</title>

    <script language="JavaScript" src="/resources/OpenLayers-2.13.1/OpenLayers.js"></script>
    <script language="JavaScript" src="/resources/proj4js/lib/proj4js-combined.js"></script>

    <script language="JavaScript" src="maptest.js"></script>
</head>

<body onload="init()">
    <h2>OpenStreetMap Test</h2>

    <div id="map" style="border: 1px solid black; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 10%; height: 300px; width:300px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

#### maptest.js

```
function init() {

    Proj4js.defs["EPSG:27700"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=49 +lon_0=-2 +k=0.9996012717 +x_0=400000 +y_0=-100000 +ellps=airy +datum=OSGB36 +units=m +no_defs ";

    var EPSG27700  = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:27700");
    var EPSG900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:900913");

    var map = new OpenLayers.Map("map",{
                    controls: [
                        new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher({'ascending':false}),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                        new OpenLayers.Control.KeyboardDefaults()
                    ]});

    var OSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OpenStreetMap");
    var OSMcycle = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("OSM Cycle", ['http://a.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png',
                                                  'http://b.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png',
                                                  'http://c.tile.thunderforest.com/cycle/${z}/${x}/${y}.png']);

    map.addLayers([OSMcycle,OSM]);

    var position = new OpenLayers.LonLat(321550,507250).transform(EPSG27700,EPSG900913);

    var markers = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
    map.addLayer(markers);
    markers.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(position));

    var zoom = 13;

    map.setCenter(position,zoom);
}
```

Without the `onload="init()"` the div is in the centre of the page, horizontally, and a short way down from the top. However, with `init()` called, the div snaps back to the left-hand side, just below the title. It still has the correct size and the border, so the CSS styling isn't being ignored completely, but I don't understand why it's not staying in position? I've tried putting the CSS into a stylesheet instead of inline, and the same thing happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OpenLayers comes with a default stylesheet that contains the following CSS

```
div.olMap {
    margin: 0 !important;
}
```

This is overriding your inline css `margin-right: auto`, `margin-left: auto`, and `margin-top: 10%`.

You can fix this by applying your preferred styles to the `#map` selector in an external style sheet (or internal).

```
#map {
    margin-left: auto !important;
    margin-right: auto !important;
    margin-top: 10% !important;
}
```

This works because your reference to an ID'ed selector, `#map`, has a higher priority than the class'ed selector, `.olMap`.

[Here's a jsfiddle of a working solution](http://jsfiddle.net/QaETr/1/).

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks! I find it peculiar how OpenLayers defines the div's margins, let alone overrides existing margins with the `!important` declaration, surely it should only be concerned with what's inside the div, and not affect its position?